# Querying if a word is a valid synonym using LucidWorks Fusion

Tags: solr, lucidworks

I took a stab at getting responses for synonyms, and was a little confused, but maybe not.  From what I could tell, synonyms are sort of a mapping that happens between doing a search and getting results, so if I wrote H2O it would search synonyms and realize that meant to say 'water'.  Where I am getting thrown off is how synonyms would be used outside of a search context, and simply as a synonym mapper for another application.

So here is where I am at.  Bellow is a call that I am making to local fusion instance however it is returning "all" the values that are stored in the synonyms list.

http://localhost:8764/api/apollo/synonyms/myCollection/

Docs
https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion/2.1.0/REST_API_Reference/Synonyms-API.html

Although this looks like a step in the right direction, I'd like to add the term on the API call, and receive a response as whether or not there is a match, and how close the match is.  From what I could tell there is no way to do that directly from the Synonyms API.  I'm assuming that we would either need to parse the Synonym list on the client sided, or there is some other API that I'd need to use.

My next option is to just write something from scratch, but was hoping i could leverage Fusions Synonym API

Comment: It would be better if you raised this question directly with LucidWorks, since it is a proprietary software and therefore their API structures won't be available publicly.

Comment: Yeah your probably right. I saw a couple Fusion question here so figured I'd give it a shot. Thanks anyway.